# where should i define my virtual hosts? conf/httpd.conf or conf.d/user.conf

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, apache-config

i have seen more than one tutorial that i have been using trying to get suPHP running on my centos 6.5 box.

first off, standard lamp virtual hosts tutorials always add virtual hosts into /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf however, a different tutorial that i was looking at (http://invision-web.net/web/install-configure-apache-php-suphp-virtual-hosts-centos/) puts the virtual hosts into /etc/httpd/conf.d/user.conf

is there a right or wrong way to do this? is one better than another?

also, i understand that httpd.conf is the main apache config file, but what exactly is the user.conf file?

Comment: Most Linux distributions fiddle with the programs they include and make small changes, esp. in the configuration files. Just go with whatever CentOS has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual host configurations should normally go in main Apache configuration file `httpd.conf`. In the article link you posted above the configuration

> creates a virtual host for user invision on domains
>   n1.invision-web.net and www.invision-web.net

. Unless you have multiple site users which require configuration at a per-user level, this is not necessary. The article does not make this clear at all.

`user.conf` is for per-user configuration. For example, where sites have multiple users (e.g. access to http://www.mysite.com/~pedro (delivering content from the home directory or sub-directory of user pedro) can be configured in the users.conf file. More details in [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/public_html.html).

Comment: in my production environment i am planning to have site1.com owned by user1 and site2.com owned by user2, but i do not wish to access sites via /~user1 or /~user2. would httpd.conf still be the correct place to put the virtual hosts?

Comment: As far as I know - yes httpd.conf would be the correct file to configure your sites.